# @+id/adView" is red, why?

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:background="#ff000640">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
   />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Why is it red? When I run the app the adview works just fine so I have no idea why it wouldn't be working. The red part also disappears for a short while once I run the app.
when I change above to below it gives no error

Comment: Not sure on this, but I think you should add AdView first and then WebView.

Comment: In addition to @Krishnabhadra words, remove the + in the above attribute of the WebView.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't sjow a minimal understanding on relative references in a RelativeLayout

Comment: Did you add the third party

Comment: @Anuja sorry for my lame knowledge about this stuff, what do you mean?

Comment: The funny thing is though, if I place the webview under the adview in the design editor, the code is fine. the moment i change android:layout_below="@+id/adView" from above to below it works. :/

Answer (score 0):

`@+id/` is used to create an id. To reference it use `@id/`. Also put the code for the adview above the code for the webview, as the id needs to be defined, before you can reference it.

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
android:background="#ff000640">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there any error message? if so, what does it say?

Comment: The red underlining says: Top level element is not completed

Comment: did you close the RelativeLayout (with `</RelativeLayout>`-tag at the end of the document) like in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

@+id/adView : the + sign means to generate a new id if it does not exist yet.
I think it would be better to

```
<WebView ...
         android:layout_above="@id/adView"
```

meaning to refer to another component with id adView
and as Krishnabhadra suggests, put the AdView declaration first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't import Google Admob Library. Please import this library into your project and try again. [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/)

Because when I try your code, any red lines appear. Just import the library.

Comment: I did that, but no difference

Comment: You should do the steps one by one from the link above.

Comment: I am using Android Studio and followed all the steps. everything in my code is fine but the @id/adView...

Comment: I just add your xml into my xml code and there is no red line. Be sure your imports and paths are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `File->Invalidate Caches...`. I've run into this before when AS doesn't re-generate the data bindings when editing layouts. Same thing sometimes happens for new string resources.