# Id tag with red underline

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've this layout in my project and AndroidStudio underlines in red the part (@+id/mylistview)  but everything works fine,
I can inflate the XML and also findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
Can't figure out the problem, by placing the mouse over I get this message
"Top level element is not completed".
By changing ListView with ExpandableListView the error disappear.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Here are some probable solutions, but none of them worked for the TO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058218/id-adview-is-red-why

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report at the link below that reports a very similar problem.  Perhaps it's an Android Studio bug?  Does it give the same error in Eclipse?  If not, probably it's the same bug reported below.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55633

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty sure what you've got here is an Android Studio bug.  You can submit a bug report; just make sure it's still an issue in the latest version.